# Checking from broken URL Images

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

I currently have the markup below using Aura.

```
<div style="{! 'background-image: url(' + v.Logo + ')'}">
</div>
```

Assuming that `v.Logo` returns a broken url for the image, what's a good way to check if it the image is broken?

In JavaScript I can use the `Image` constructor to check this, but it seems like this constructor isn't available with LockerService turned on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is now exposed with LockerService enabled. Let us know if you have any issues using the API.